# Add Monochrome effect to YUV frames in Android / NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, video-streaming, yuv, monochrome

I am trying to add monochrome effect to YUV frames. I tried to explore but no solution is working . Can anybody suggest any approach to this.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly whatyou mean by "monochrome". But if you mean grayscale, then can't you do that by setting the U and V components to 0?

Comment: I guess i was doing it wrong way . Although i was trying to do something like this but not correctly.